# How can I use alertview clickedbutton to update values in msql?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I want to use this void

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"One point，Not good"])
{
}
```

connect to mysql and update the value in column named scores.

for example

five points in column in the beginning,and I press alertview button "One point"

then the value column will change to six points.

I dont know how to use this void to do this,and I've searched lots of information,but I didnt get it

I use json and php to connect to mysql,and I use phpmyadmin.

Whether I do wrong,or this void cant used on this.

Comment: Just want to let you know that there's nothing wrong with your syntax. All the posted answers are telling you to use a different implementation.  The only thing "bad" about yours is if you decide to change the title of a button, this implementation will break without changing the title here. Conversely, some of the solutions below will break if the order of the buttons ever changes.

Answer (score 1):

First set the tag value for your UIAlertview then

you should use the button index value not its string text

//I have just take the tag value as 204

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(alertView.tag==204 && buttonIndex==1)
{

   //your logic

}

else if(alertView.tag==204 && buttonIndex==0)
{

   //your logic

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the button Index

```
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
// write the logic here
return;
}
else if(buttonIndex == 2)
{
// write the logic here
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you have to use is this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

For using this function your ViewController have to implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate`

in the `.h` `yourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

example

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //do something if you press the "cancel" button
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //do other thing with other button
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIAlertView delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //do something if you press the "cancel" button
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //do other thing with other button
    }
}
```

For multiple UIAlertView you can set **Tag** for each alert view.

Also you need to set Delegate For UIAlertView: **UIAlertViewDelegate**

Answer (score 0):

The (void) at the beginning of the method declaration just indicates that the method does not return any value after the code has executed. On the other hand, a declaration like:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

indicates that an NSInteger will be returned at the end of the method, so you could actually set the method equal to a variable like so:

```
NSInteger number = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:scoreTable];
```

In the case of your question, if you are looking to update some MySQL tables that are living on a remote server via PHP, you'll need to create a method that can use NSURLConnection to POST a value to a PHP script on your server.  It's pretty far out of scope for me to answer specifically, because it should really be broken up into smaller questions.

Question 1: How do I write my PHP script?

1. Declare incoming $_['POST'] variables that will be in the message body
2. Make the mysql_connect to your database
3. Write the SQL statement to retrieve the record to update, and update it

Question 2: How do I POST an update to a webserver with NSURLConnection

1. Create an NSURL object with the URL to your .php script that handles MySQL updates
2. Create an NSMutableURLRequest, give it the NSURL and set the HTTPMethod property to @"POST"
3. The hard part is to create the bodyData, which will be the encoded headers that correspond to the $_['POST'] variables in your PHP script.
4. Create an NSURLConnection object, set the request property to your NSMutableURLRequest and set the Delegate to receive callback information
5. Start the NSURLConnection

I think if you search on SO you can find the answer to both of these questions.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, to check wether the right button has been clicked or not, you should use something defined in some header file.
For example:

```
#define CORRECT_BUTTON_TITLE @"One point，Not good"
```

and then, do your check

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
    if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:CORRECT_BUTTON_TITLE])
    {
       // UPDATE YOUR DATABASE
    }}
```

That should allow you to modify your names easily in one single shot and avoid mistakes.

**Second**, how to update your database. Simply, you have to send instructions to a PHP file located on your server, "next to" your MySQL database. Your instructions are sent via an HTTP POST request.
In your php,

```
if( isset($_POST["updateScore"]) and isset($_POST["newScore"])) ){
   $newScore = intval( $_POST["newScore"] );
   // execute mysql queries
}
```

In XCode, you can use ASIHTTPRequest to send POST requests. Let's say your PHP file is located at `www.example.com/update.php`.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {
        if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:CORRECT_BUTTON_TITLE])
        {
           // UPDATE YOUR DATABASE
           NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/update.php"];
           ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
           [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"updateScore"];
           [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 6] forKey:@"newScore"];
           [request setDelegate:self];
           [request startAsynchronous];
        }}
```